# How to compare two arrays based on their occurrences without using filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Hello All Can you help me creating a function where I can remove elements from array based on their occurrences

For example consider below two array:

```
array 1 = [1,1,1,2,2]

array 2 = [1]
```

Expected Result for above:

```
array 3 = [1,1,2,2]
```

For example consider below two array

```
array 1 = [1,1,1,2,2]

array 2 = [1,1]
```

Expected Result for above:

```
array 3 = [1,2,2]
```

I used filter but it removes all occurences of 1

```
array1 = array1.filter(item => array2.indexOf(item) < 0);
```

I need a function in javascript which will remove matched no of occurence for both arrays

Comment: What you have tried? I mean - Just iterate, check and remove!

Comment: You mean using two for loops  ?

Comment: I did but i dont want all occurences to remove at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check for the occurrence in `array2` and remove it if found using `splice`.

```js
const array1 = [1,1,1,2,2]
const array2 = [1,1]
const output = []

array1.forEach(item => {
  const array2Index = array2.indexOf(item);
  if (array2Index > -1) {
    // remove array2 occurance
    array2.splice(array2Index, 1);
  } else {
    output.push(item)
  }
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: He has mentioned he does'nt want to use `filter`.

Comment: I have gave upvote & accepted the answer as well thank you :)